# secondary monitor not recognised on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I've just bought a Dell Alienware m17x laptop, and tried to connect my monitor on VGA, and HDMI as well, neither worked. Of course I've already done it a thousand times on my Windows XP PC, but on Windows 7 it just doesn't recognize it. I have a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 260M video card, tried reinstalling drivers, but didn't work. Installed the monitors drivers (Samsung Syncmaster 2343), and it is shown in the device manager, but under the screen resolution panel it's not shown, whether I hit identify, or detect.I cannot extend the display to this one.

Comment: What edition of Win 7 are you using? Lower end versions of Win 7 do not support multiple monitors. Also try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976064

Comment: Ganesh R.: As far as I know, only the Starter edition lacks multiple-monitor support.  Then again, Starter also lacks the ability to change your wallpaper.  Starter only ships on netbooks, and the lowest Windows edition Alienware ships currently is Home Premium.  Can you try hooking up another monitor or a TV?

Comment: Using win7 Home premium x64, so the problem can't be with that. Looked at the link, tried them already, nothing helped. When the monitor is not connected, it says check signal table, but when I plug into the laptop, it just goes blank,and even recognises in device manager. But Not with Win+p combination, not in screen resolution menu can extend the display(When i extend with win+p, nothing happens. Tried connectiong a TV on HDMI, the same happens. Wot can be the problem? Registry??